# mixed-effect vs ols regression?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, least-squares

I have a data set containing ratings from participants on a number of variables concerning different situations (level 1) as well as participant characteristic scores (level 2). In previous models, I was using lmer in the lme4 model to look at associations among the level 1 variables, and treating both participant and situation category as random factors.

Now I want to predict participant characteristics using the situation variables, but because you can't use level 2 variables as DVs I get a singular fit.  I can run the models and get results if I treat only situation type as a random factor, but I am not sure if it is valid to do so.  Would it be better to aggregate situation level scores as averages and run an OLS regression (even though I lose some information), or to run the mixed-effect model treating only situation and not person as a random factor?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this an issue with the theory or a limitation of the particular software?

Comment: with the theory